# sed -unterminated `s' command

Tags: python, sed

I used the following sed command to find and replace an old string with a new one:

```
  cmd = "sed -i 's/"+oldstr+"/"+newstr+"/'"+ "path_to/filename" #change the string in the file
  os.system(cmd) # am calling the sed command in my python script
```

But i get this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unterminated `s' command
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my sed command?
Or is anything wrong in the way I have given the file name?

Update:
echo of that command: 
sed -i 's/6.9.28
/6.9.29/' dirname/filename

Comment: echo that `cmd`, show us what's in there...

Comment: looks like something in either `oldstr` or `newstr`. as @Wrikken noted, echo on error because you seem to have a tick just before "s" --- are you bound to use `sed` for this operation?

Comment: Using `sed` in a python script seems pretty silly and a dirty hack, and would break portability. If it is intended to be run in linux only, then it's ok. And `os.system` is deprecated too, use the `subprocess` module.

Comment: echo of command: sed -i 's/6.9.28 /6.9.29/' dirname/filename

Comment: To answer the question: there is nothing that is not wrong with that command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without calling `sed`

```
with open("path_to/filename") as f:
    file_lines = f.readlines()
    new_file = [line.replace(oldstr,newstr) for line in file_lines]

open("path_to/filename","w").write(''.join(new_file))
```

EDIT:

Incorporating Joran's comment:

```
with open("path_to/filename") as f:
    file = f.read()
    newfile = file.replace(oldstr,newstr)

open("path_to/filename","w").write(newfile)
```

or even

```
with open("path_to/filename") as f:
    open("path_to/filename","w").write(f.read().replace(oldstr,newstr))
```

Comment: couldnt you just read() instead of readlines and only do one replace (since it should replace all occurences?)

Comment: Interesting - it worked for me (I tested before posting). Glad there was something useful in there, though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the only thing wrong, but you probably want a space preceding the path name, to separate it from the command:

```
cmd = "sed -i 's/%s/%s/' %s"%(oldstr, newstr, "path_to/filename")
```

(I switched to the string formatting operator to make the overall structure of the `sed` command line easier to see).

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what is going wrong with your command. Anyway, you would certainly get better on using the [subprocess.call()](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) function. Suppose we have the file:

```
$ cat test.txt 
abc
def
```

Now, if I execute the following program:

```
import subprocess
oldstr = 'a'
newstr = 'AAA'
path = 'test.txt'
subprocess.call(['sed', '-i', 's/'+oldstr+'/'+newstr+'/', path])
```

We get this:

```
$ cat test.txt 
AAAbc
def
```

Also, if your `oldstr`/`newstr` has some slash (`/`) inside, your command will broke too. We can solve it by replacing the slashes by an escaped slash:

```
>>> print 'my/string'.replace('/', '\\/')
my\/string
```

So, if you have this file:

```
$ cat test.txt 
this is a line and/or a test
this is also a line and/or a test
```

and you want to replace `and/or`, just replace the slashes accordingly in the variables:

```
import subprocess
oldstr = 'and/or'
newstr = 'AND'
path = 'test.txt'
subprocess.call(['sed', '-i', 's/'+oldstr.replace('/', '\\/')+'/'+newstr.replace('/', '\\/')+'/', path])
```

Of course, it can be a bit more readable:

```
import subprocess
oldstr = 'and/or'
newstr = 'AND'
path = 'test.txt'
sedcmd = 's/%s/%s/' % (oldstr.replace('/', '\\/'), newstr.replace('/', '\\/'))
subprocess.call(['sed', '-i', sedcmd, path])
```

Comment: used this  : `import subprocess
oldstr = 'and/or'
newstr = 'AND'
path = 'test.txt'
sedcmd = 's/%s/%s/' % (oldstr.replace('/', '\\/'), newstr.replace('/', '\\/'))
subprocess.call(['sed', '-i', sedcmd, path])` and it still shows the same error